# Can we use event.preventDefault() in angularjs application?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic application while page load each time it's loading the login page then it's coming to profile page . I think if this works i can can use it in profile controller so that each time i can see the current page which is getting refresh.

Can any body help me out to achieve this?

Again when i am navigating to each page using `$state.go("app.profile")` or `$state.go("app.signup")`, Each time it's loading `login.html` as a splash screen & later it's navigating to the requested page.

My requirement is if I refresh the profile page or signup page it should only reload the current page not login page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ionic 2 uses angular 2.. not angularjs...which version of ionic?

Comment: my ionic application version is 2.2.1

Comment: can you add some code? what is `$state.`?

Comment: how is that related to `preventDefault()`?

Comment: for routing to different page i am using state . i have configured it in config property of angular module . Please refer the below code
    .state('app.signup', {
        url: './signup',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
                controller: 'SignupCtrl'
               
            }
        }
    })

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer to prevent default action from happening we use preventDefault & in my application by default in each page load it's going to login page first

Comment: ionic 2 uses [navcontroller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) not angular router.. can you give a sample plunker maybe?

Comment: @SP how is going to a page an event? `preventDefault()` is for DOM events.

Comment: @suraj here is my code is for profile controller , Everything is working fine except this 
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope,Auth,$window, $rootScope, $stateParams, $timeout,$interval, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, Groups, ionicMaterialMotion,ionicMaterialInk, $ionicPopup,$state) {

}

Comment: this looks like _ionic 1_ and _angularjs_ . are you sure of which version you are using??

Comment: `$scope` is in angular v1

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer using ng-click= function() in html page we can pass the arguments as function parameters & same thing we can acess in perticular controller

Comment: yes @suraj  i am using angular 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass the event to the function and handle it from there, it's the clean and best way doing it:

in your view(html):

```
<button (click)="clicked($event)">click</button>
```

and in your Javascript (Typescript):

```
clicked(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //then do whatever you should do here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All ,

My problem got solved . I made two changes in my app. 
used preventDefault() as required . 
And i changed the $stateProvider to $routeProvider.
inside app.config i put the below code

```js
  $routeProvider
         .when("/app", {
            // controller: AppCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
    })       .when("/signup", {
        //   controller: SignupCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html'
    })       .when("/profile", {
       //  controller: ProfileCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return `false` in the event handler

```
(click)="onClick($event);false"
```

or

```
(click)="onClick($event)"
```

```
onClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // or
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Let me go through it . Thank you so much !!

Comment: @suraj  Thanks, I missed that the angular2 tag has been removed.